# I have number and symbol mixed string how to make it as completely functonal in python

Tags: python-3.x

a = "9+10"

print(int(a))

i try to loop thorough it and split them out through error handling try method and it works but i need to know that is there any simple way to do it. I should get 19, but a value shouldn't change need to work with mixed string.also should work with all the operations.

Comment: If you want to throw caution to the wind, `print(eval("9 + 10"))` but you might want to build an expression parser for safety. If you want `a` to be 19 then `exec("a = 9 + 10")` again with some risk.

Comment: I don't think its a this easy job, i have created a whole eval functionality on my own